# Hive should not remove trailing zeros for decimal numbers

Tags: hadoop, hive

I know that this issue is fixed in hive 0.14 
[here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/HIVE-7373)
but I am still facing this issue in HDP2.2 hive 0.14.

I am trying to insert a value `345.00` into hive table col1 decimal(5,2). But it is storing the value as `345` but not `345.00`

My expectation is hive should store the value `345.00`

Do I need to enable any additional settings to enable this behavior in hive 0.14. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `345` is the same number as `345.00`. Formatting of decimal digits should be done in the frontend when _displaying_ the value. It should not be part of the storage

Comment: technically both the values are same but my client is migrating from existing Datawarehouse to hive. Keeping the reporting/frontend system as it is. So he is expecting the same behavior in hive aswell. However this issue was addressed in hive 0.14 as per the JIRA ticket HIVE-7373. Since i am using the version i would like to use this functionality.

Comment: i have faced similar issue in my current project and looks like it is hive limitation. BTW i am using hive 0.14 hdp2.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

if your decimal column value = 345 OR

```
cast(cast("345" as Decimal(5,2)) as STRING)
```

if your decimal column value = 345.00

```
cast(cast("345.00" as Decimal(5,2)) as STRING)
```

then write to file.

I hope this is helpful.